# How can I sniff LoRaWAN packages?

Tags: sensors, packet-sniffers, lorawan

I have a temperature, humidity and pressure sensor working over LoRaWAN, I can get the read with the phone by NFC.

Also, I have some Arduino projects working with ESP32 and RFM9X (LoRa) boards to exchange data between the radio modules.

I want to sniff the LoraWAN packages exchanged between radio boards or between the sensor and another device.

How I can do that with Wireshark?

I already have a CC2531USB dongle. I am using it for ZigBee packets. Can I use it for Lora and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to capture LoRaWAN uplink messages, you need a LoRaWAN gateway. In order to capture downlink messages, you need an end device. The difference between UL and DL messages is that DL is sent with inverse polarization. This is why sniffing LoRaWAN messages is not so easy.
The easiest way to see what is going on between a LoRaWAN end device and a network is to use a packet logger that is usually provided by a network server.
One of the best packet logger is Actility's Wireless Logger, that you can try on the [ThingPark Community portal](https://community.thingpark.org).